# NPM install failing with 502 error

Tags: node.js, curl, npm, codeship

This is a rather obscure issue. I have an Angular app that will be running through Codeship for CI. However, when it comes time to run `npm install` on the Codeship box, npm gives back

```
-npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.templatesettings/-/lodash.templatesettings-2.4.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 502
\npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.templatesettings/-/lodash.templatesettings-2.4.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 502
\npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.templatesettings/-/lodash.templatesettings-2.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/rof/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/home/rof/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4

npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 502
```

This was quite strange, since the `npm install` worked just fine on my box. My first instinct was that it had to be an issue with the NPM repository, so I grabbed the url for the package(https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.templatesettings/-/lodash.templatesettings-2.4.1.tgz) and threw it into a new Chrome tab. Sure enough, the archive downloaded almost instantly. I was confused by this, so I tried the Codeship build again, but got the same results. I decided to SSH into the Codeship box to see if I could access it. I ran

`curl https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.templatesettings/-/lodash.templatesettings-2.4.1.tgz`

and as I expected I got the 502 error. However, when I ran the same command from the terminal on my machine, I got the same result, even though the `npm install` ran perfectly for me. I wasn't able to find anyone else having this type of an issue, and a 502 seems like a very rare code for the NPM registry to be returning. Any ideas?

Comment: The questions is about a problem occurring right now on npm registry servers. @andrey Romashin's answers link to the ongoing discussion and is enough to be informed, but future discussions shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with the **registry.npmjs.org** in some regions.

Here is issue:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13284

Answer (score 6):

Try to keep one registry inside `.npmrc` file, only one of them works. 
The order of registry also does matter. Also try to set:

- `npm config delete proxy`
- `npm config delete https-proxy`

to clean proxy inside terminal.

Comment: This fixed this issue for me. Been happening on and off for weeks and this is the only thing that has fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same issue via npm install on Ubuntu 14 running on AWS

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/combine-lists/-/combine-lists-1.0.0.tgz
```

returns 502 Bad Gateway from the ubuntu server, but works fine from local client

There's an open issue at NPM for this:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13284

Answer (score 2):

NPM just acknowledged the issue and they are working on it. Your can track  the status at below link.

http://status.npmjs.org

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while publishing my package on npm. After banging my head against the wall for a few hours, I realized I was on mobile hotsopt. I switched to wifi and bang there was my package on npm!

Comment: What has mobile hotspot to do with it? I am permanently on mobile hotspot for internet access and I don't have WiFi. Any way I can solve the problem this case?